# Visual Studio 2010 Snippet Generator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a good tool to generate snippets for Visual Studio 2010 without having to manually edit XML

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you are: [Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)